# i'm using Android Studio 3.5.3 . inside my android project "local.properties" file code automatically changed what is the reason

Tags: android

after i restarted project then my project level  all gradle file code changed due to below denoted problem. sir now my intension is what is the reason to aumatically chaged my local.properties file. if our one file issue found then our whole project going to crash.this problem of android studio i facing lots of time what is the reason please anybody give me solution

before local.properties file code

```
    # Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file should *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\ajay\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

after autimatically chaged local.properties file

```
Êþº¾   3 ˆ
  ƒ … † abc_action_bar_home_description I 
ConstantValue   abc_action_bar_up_description  $abc_action_menu_overflow_description  abc_action_mode_done  !abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all  *abc_activitychooserview_choose_application  abc_capital_off  abc_capital_on  abc_font_family_body_1_material  abc_font_family_body_2_material   abc_font_family_button_material 
  abc_font_famil
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open `local.properties` file locally in a text editor, and see if you still get the same result.

There seems to be a problem with your Android Studio. I would suggest downloading [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) from its official website, and then reopen your project in there.

## EDIT

If `local.properties` is corrupted locally, then you will need to reinstall android studio and import your project again. Are your gradle build scripts corrupted as well or is it just the local.properties file? If multiple files are corrupted then either Android Studio is corrupted or some other background service or malicious program is causing havoc in your file system. What OS are you on? (I hope not windows)

Comment: yes sir ...i was already checked local.properties file inside text editor but still showing me crahed file

Comment: i was dowloaded android studio from official website of android

Comment: i'm using  windows system

Comment: Then try to do a new install for the android studio. You can import the previous setting to preserve state and re-import your project and see if it builds or not. If the same issue occurs, then try to clean your file system by removing all the hazardous softwares or programs.

Comment: Please accept the answer for others users. Thank you.